# PostgreSQL: How to search a list of strings as a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's been a while since I've had to do any db work, so I'm not really sure how to ask this and I know I've done it in the past.
How do you create a temporary table out of a list of strings (not using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE)?  So, if you have something like :

- > '1', 'a', 'A'
  >   '2', 'b', 'B'
  >   '3', 'c', 'C'
- ```
  SELECT  field2 
  FROM    { {'1','a','A'}, {'2','b','B'}, {'3','c','C'} } 
          AS fooarray(field1,field2,field3)
  WHERE   field1 = '2'
  -- should return 'b'
  ```

Hint: It's similar to...

- ```
  SELECT * FROM unnest(array[...]);
  ```

Comment: What's wrong with using `unnest`

Comment: For 1, it's not working too well with multidimensional arrays.  But let's just say that I have a one-dimensional array, I'm still struggling with joining on an existing table `select lower(letter) from (select * from unnest('{"A","B","C"}') as letter) as foo where lower(letter) not in (select lower(letter) from someothertable);`

Comment: Update: So I don't know what the joining problem was, but it is joining fine now.  Still the multiple dimensions is somewhat of a problem.  I wanted to use only native functions and avoid using any sort of stored proc to unnest the dimensions.  -- mu's `values` is what I was looking for, and probably what I did in the past

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to mess around with arrays at all, you can build the table in-place using [VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html):

> **7.7. VALUES Lists**
>
> `VALUES` provides a way to generate a "constant table" that can be used in a query without having to actually create and populate a table on-disk.

See also [VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html).

So you can do things like this:

```
=> select *
   from (
       values ('1', 'a', 'A'),
              ('2', 'b', 'B'),
              ('3', 'c', 'C')
    ) as t(id, c1, c2)
    where id = '2';

 id | c1 | c2 
----+----+----
 2  | b  | B
(1 row)
```

Don't forget to give your VALUES an alias complete with column names (`t(id, c1, c2)`) so that everything has a name.

Comment: For some reason I thought I was using the `{{},{}}` syntax, but then I remembered I used values as well.  Either way, this is what I needed.  Should you also specify the datatypes on the alias (eg `t(id::numeric,c1::text,c2::text)`)?

Comment: @vol7ron: AFAIK you'd have to specify the data types inside each of the VALUES, you probably don't need them though, the types should be inferred just fine.